# Determining if a memory leak is occurring in Python

Tags: python, garbage-collection, cpython

My understanding is that a memory leak in Python (> Cpython 2.0 at least) can *only occur* under the following circumstances:

1. A circular reference graph that contains one or more objects
   with a `__del__` method
2. An extension C/C++ or other native code module that executes and leaks memory internally

Of course, we need to make a distinction between an ***actual memory leak*** (a program where objects can never be reclaimed via the Garbage Collector or regular reference counting) versus a program which simply runs out of memory because it keeps allocating objects which never die - (but remain in reach) - usually because their reference graph connects with some global variable.

In order to distinguish between these two circumstances (i.e. actual memory leak vs. program which just keeps allocating collectable objects which never go out of reach), can we simply continuously call `gc.collect()` and check that the return value is `0` ?

In other words, if the following program never fails with an `AssertionError` (due to the assertion in Thread 2) have we effectively *proved* that there is ***no memory leak*** (as defined above)?

```
Thread 1:
   ... run actual application code ...

Thread 2:
  while True:
    num = gc.collect()
    assert num == 0
    time.sleep(WAIT_TIME)
```

To be clear, I'm only asking if this program would prove that an actual memory leak, as defined by cases (1) and (2) above is NOT happening - I realize it wouldn't prove that the program will never run out of memory due to too many allocations.

Comment: Ref this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage Just because an object is currently unreachable, I don't think that means it can never be collected. E.g. I think cycle of objects with `__del__` will be reported as unreachable but you if you subsequently manually break the cycle then the GC will be able to collect them.

Comment: Note that python3.4 changed quite a bit the part about cycles and `__del__` methods, so in python3.4 the gc is able to collect much more cases of cycles than before. Read the What's new section [*Safe object finalization*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-442) and [PEP-442](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).

Answer (score 0):

This program is very likely to throw an `AssertionError` even if there is no memory leak.  It will do so any time the GC collects anything (`gc.collect()` returns nonzero in that case).  OTOH, `gc.collect()` does not collect what you refer to as "actual memory leaks," so they will *not* be reported in the `gc.collect()` return value.

In short, no, this program will not detect memory leaks correctly at all.  If you want to catch case (1), you can periodically check to make sure `gc.garbage` is empty, but that will not catch case (2), because the GC only becomes involved in managing an extension module's memory if the module asks (and even then, only to the extent that the module correctly tracks its owned references).  You need something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for the general case.

Comment: Hmm... I'm confused.  The docs don't seem to agree with what you're saying.  The docs say the `gc.collect()`: number of unreachable objects found is returned. (See https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect).  Am I misunderstanding the meaning of "unreachable objects found" ?  I thought that `gc.collect()` will basically return the number of objects it can't destroy due to them having a `__del__` method - but I understand your point about C modules - certainly `gc.collect()` has no way of knowing about general C allocation

Comment: The "number of unreachable objects found" means "the number of objects which were eligible for collection."  I'm not entirely sure if that includes case (1), but it certainly includes anything which actually was collected, and it cannot possibly include case (2) because the GC may not be aware of case (2) objects in the first place (e.g. because your extension module just calls `malloc()` and leaks the result).